# Merge two dictionaries if the keys are equal

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I have 2 dictionaries.

I need to merge them together based on key:value pairs. If any key:value item in either the first or second dictionary dont match they are added as separate pairs to the final dict.

Comment: please don't vandalize your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be not efficient but naive way may be to iterate over items in each dictionary and add in new dictionary:

```
Dict1 = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [5], 'c': [5, 6, 9]}
dict2 = {'a': [4], 'b': [8, 9, 0], 'd': [10, 14, 13]}

# to store final result of dictionary
result = {}

# iterate through each dictionary in list
for dictionary in [Dict1, dict2]:
    # iterate through key value of dictionary items
    for k,v in dictionary.items():
        # if key is already in result dictionary then extend new values
        if k in result.keys():
            result[k].extend(v)
        # else if key is not in dictionary then add key with the first value
        else:
            result[k] = v

print(result)
```

Result:

```
{'d': [10, 14, 13], 'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [5, 8, 9, 0], 'c': [5, 6, 9]}
```

**Note** as @chepner pointed out in comments below, the above solution changes the `Dict1` so, using `deepcopy` would avoid it, and other is `.keys()` is not required while checking for if key exists in dictionary:

```
from copy import deepcopy

Dict1 = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [5], 'c': [5, 6, 9]}
dict2 = {'a': [4], 'b': [8, 9, 0], 'd': [10, 14, 13]}

# to store final result of dictionary
result = {}

# iterate through each dictionary in list
for dictionary in [deepcopy(Dict1), dict2]:
    # iterate through key value of dictionary items
    for k,v in dictionary.items():
        # if key is already in result dictionary then extend new values
        if k in result:
            result[k].extend(v)
        # else if key is not in dictionary then add key with the first value
        else:
            result[k] = v

print(result)
```

Comment: You don't need the call to `keys`; the `dict` iterator already produces the keys.

Comment: Note that this will modify the lists in `Dict1` as you update `result`, since you didn't make a copy of the values.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, I will add the edit section to point it out.

Comment: The shallow copy made by `Dict1.copy()` isn't sufficient; it makes a new `dict`, but each dict still refers to the same values.

Comment: @chepner thanks, I didn't know that, how about using `result[k] = v[:]` in `else` loop to avoid changing `Dict1`?

Comment: For downvote, is there anything I can update? or if this is really bad solution then, I can remove the answer too.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon thanks for the reply, I replaced with `deepcopy`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.get` to return an empty list when an item is not in your list. This allows to get the desired output with a single dict comprehension, by looping over the existing keys.

```
d1 = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [5], 'c': [5, 6, 9]}
d2 = {'a': [4], 'b': [8, 9, 0], 'd': [10, 14, 13]}

output = {k: d1.get(k, []) + d2.get(k, []) for k in {*d1, *d2}}
# output: {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [5, 8, 9, 0], 'c': [5, 6, 9], 'd': [10, 14, 13]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultdict`:

```
final_dict = defaultdict(list)

for d in [Dict1, dict2]:
    for k, v in d.items():
        final_dict[k].extend(v)
```

and the result is:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'c': [5, 6, 9], 'b': [5, 8, 9, 0], 'd': [10, 14, 13]})
```

Comment: A shorter way is to do `final_dict = defaultdict(list, **deepcopy(Dict1))` so you can remove your outter loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
dict1 = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [5], 'c': [5, 6, 9]}
dict2 = {'a': [4], 'b': [8, 9, 0], 'd': [10, 14, 13]}
new_l = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(list(dict1.items())+list(dict2.items()), key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
final_result = {a:list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([c for _, c in b])) for a, b in new_l}
```

Output:

```
{'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [5, 8, 9, 0], 'c': [5, 6, 9], 'd': [10, 14, 13]}
```